# How to upgrade my android application from lite to pro version

Tags: android

I developed a android application, which is lite version.

Now I added some new features and that I want to release as a pro version.

From my lite version app I need to read its data base also.

Can somebody tell me what changes I need to do in my current app so that I can access to my older /data/data/package/databases/aba.db folder.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this would be to use an in-app purchase to buy a "license key" that would allow the "lite" version to gain the extra features and therefore become the "pro" version.

You can check at the relevant points in your app if the license key has been purchased and change your UI to offer the feature set that is relevant to the current mode.